# SQL Server: basic query with the use of trigger or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

2 Tables

- Sales Order
- Delivery

Sales order:

```
   -------------------
   |ID  | Name | Qty |
   -------------------
   | 1  | S01  | 100 |
   | 2  | S02  | 100 |
   | 3  | S03  | 100 |
   -------------------
```

Delivery:

```
   --------------------
   |ID   | Name | Qty |
   --------------------
   |  1  | D01  | 100 |
   |  2  | D02  | 50  |
   |  3  | D03  | 50  |
   |  4  | D04  | 50  |
   --------------------
```

S02 which has 100 qty needs to be transferred to D02 and D03  how can I put it in my query. With the use of a stored procedure or trigger or partial? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You just did a great job in the last 7mn :)

Comment: thank you for editing my post :) . Sorry for my unproffesionalism

Comment: the question is very very vague. what code have you tried? what are you actually trying to accomplish? are you evenly dividing the sales order quantity? how many deliveries are you splitting to? always 2? sometimes 1 or more than 2?